# naming output file in while loop

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file `input.txt` with three columns

```
A B Z
C D Y
E F X
```

I want to read the first two fields, perform some function and name the output with the last field.

```
while IFS=" " read -r f1 f2 f3; do cat $f1 $f2 > $f3; done < file.txt
```

How can I apply this to longer codes

the `input.sample.text` has following three columns

```
../Data/G20P1sc-C05-R1.fastq.gz ../Data/G20P1sc-C05-R1.fastq.gz G20P1sc-C05
../Data/G20P1sc-C08-R1.fastq.gz ../Data/G20P1sc-C08-R1.fastq.gz G20P1sc-C08
```

```
 while IFS=" " read -r f1 f2 f3; do rsem-calculate-expression --star --star-path /share/pkg/star/2.7.0e/bin --temporary-folder --star-gzipped-read-file --paired-end $f1 $f2 ../genome_indices/rsem-star/rsem-star ../test_results/$f3; done < src_pdm3012/input.sample.text
```

The output has the following error

```
EXITING: FATAL INPUT ERROR: empty value for parameter "outFileNamePrefix" in input "Command-Line-Initial"
SOLUTION: use non-empty value for this parameter
```

I try to explicitly use the `--outFileNamePrefix` and it still has the same error

```
while IFS=" " read -r f1 f2 f3; do rsem-calculate-expression --star --star-path /share/pkg/star/2.7.0e/bin --temporary-folder --star-gzipped-read-file --paired-end $f1 $f2 ../genome_indices/rsem-star/rsem-star --outFileNamePrefix $f3; done < ../src_pdm3012/input.sample.text
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "longer codes"?

Comment: I was hoping I could apply this to mapping multiple fastq files and naming the output.

Comment: Something Like this:  ```while IFS=" " read -r f1 f2 f3; do rsem-calculate-expression --star --star-path /share/pkg/star/2.7.0e/bin --temporary-folder  --star-gzipped-read-file --paired-end $f1 $f2 ../genome_indices/rsem-star/rsem-star --outFileNamePrefix $f3; done < ../src_pdm3012/input.sample.text``` But it does not work

Comment: How does it "not work"? What are the error messages? I'd suggest editing your question and putting this very relevant information in it.

Comment: please see the edited question. I have put in the error message too.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest `awk` script to do this:

```
awk '{ print $1,$2 > $3}'
```

Of course you must be sure that `$3` exists (and is unique) and that there is no confution what the third column is, i.e. columns 1, 2, and 3 should not contain field separators.

`awk` will also allow you manyfold manipulations on the first two columns.

Comment: It's not clear what this does that the code in the question does not do.

Comment: @Kusalananda "longer codes" and "perform some function" in the question is a bit unspecific. It could well be a problem fitting for `awk` with this answer just showing how to get a column as per-line filename for the output.

Comment: this code write line field $1 and line field $2 into output file named by line field $3

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect a command group or any form of compound command to redirect the output of more than one command, whether it's a while loop or not:

```
while IFS=" " read -r f1 f2 f3; do
  {
    cat < "$f1"
    echo whatever
    cat < "$f2"
    echo end
  } > "$f3"
done < file.txt
```

Also remember that in POSIX shells, variables expansions need to be quoted.

Comment: @Stéphan..can you show how to write the above code for ```rsem-calculate-expression``` in while loop ? I guess, the difference from your answer in format is , in my code the output will be within the brackets.